# Can't load RSS XML with namespace

Tags: php, xml, apache, rss

I have Apache 2.4 running on RHEL and have the following XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss>
<channel>
<title>This is a test</title>
<link>http://example.com/</link>
<description>This is a test</description>
<language>en-us</language>
<lastBuildDate>Wed, 06 Apr 2016 13:37:53 -0400</lastBuildDate>
<docs>http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss</docs>
<generator>Test</generator>
</channel>
</rss>
```

This loads just fine as expected in the browser. Now if this is changed to -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">
    <channel>
    <title>This is a test</title>
    <link>http://example.com/</link>
    <description>This is a test</description>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <lastBuildDate>Wed, 06 Apr 2016 13:37:53 -0400</lastBuildDate>
    <docs>http://blogs.law.harvard.edu/tech/rss</docs>
    <generator>Test</generator>
    </channel>
    </rss>
```

I get "the connection was reset". There is nothing in the apache access or error logs that can point to what might be causing this to not load. Also if I remove version="2.0" xmlns:xhtml="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" and add something like blah="blah" it works. The version or namespace declaration causes the XML to not load. Any help to approach this problem will be highly appreciated.

**MORE DETAILS AS PER THE COMMENTS**

1. The XML file is static and not generated but PHP or any other code
2. If I change the extension to .txt or .html, it works just fine.
3. If I have version or namespace attribute (one or the other), the file does not render. So both these fails- `<rss version="2.0">` `<rss xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/">`
4. If I rename the node `<rss>` to `<rss1>`, it works.
5. Tested all browsers, also wget and same results
6. PHP is installed on this server. Can any extensions cause this?

Comment: Why do you need the `version` tag? ( Have you tried without it? )

Comment: Your problem seems rather strange. The XML is produced by php? In this case, can you show the code? Then, you have tried in more than one browser? For me, the xml is valid and I have not problems to load it. Note that `xmlns:xhtml ="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/` doesn't appear standard namespace: generally is used `xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/ `. I don't think that the problem is Apache.

Comment: @PhilippBraun - Thank you. Please check the new details I just added

Comment: @fusion3k- My bad. the namespace was actually xmlns:media and not xhtml. I was just trying to see if changing it to something else would do any good. Yes I tried on all latest browsers + also did wget to that file and no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening over a limited access VPN that had restrictions for RSS and MP4 traffic.